# App layout and callback for a Dash-Leaflet map

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, geopandas, dash-leaflet

I am adding a Dash-Leaflet map to a callback and want to know how to setup up the app layout. Below are the modules and datasets used.

```
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, dash_table
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import dash_leaflet as dl
import dash_leaflet.express as dlx
import geopandas as gpd
import json


df = df[["Analysis","LGA", "SMA","AVLU", "Address","Locality", "AREA(HA)","Sale Date"]]
gdf1 = gdf[["ANALYSISID","geometry"]]
sales =gdf1.merge(dfb, left_on='ANALYSISID', right_on='Analysis')


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY])
app.layout = html.Div([

####app layout code for 4 dropdowns, a radio button, a table, 2 graphs, and 2 statistical ouputs.####
```

Below is a snippet of the app layout code I have been writing but have not been successful in connecting to a callback and returning a figure.

```
############################################################################### map layout

    dbc.Row(
        [
            dbc.Col(
                    dl.Map([
                    dl.TileLayer(),  # <-- default basemap
                    geojson,                      
                    id="map", style={'width': '100%', 'height': '80vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"},
                ])
         
            ),
            
        ],
)


@app.callback(
    Output('graph-container1', 'children'),    
    Output('graph-container', 'children'),
    Output('table-container', 'data'),
    Output('my_output', 'children'),
    Output('my_output1', 'children'),
    Output('map', 'children'),
    Input('factor2', 'value'),
    Input('factor1', 'value'),
    Input('radio_items', 'value'),   
    Input('SMA-dpdn', 'value'), 
    Input('LGA-dpdn', 'value'),

prevent_initial_call=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have not used **dash-leaflet** before.   Simply it works the same as any type of **dash** component when returned from a **callback**
- have sourced / generated some data so your initial data frame code works
- have created a very rudimentary layout that is layout indicated by parameters you provided to `@app.callback()`
- in line with first point, changed **callback** to pass **list** of inputs and **list** of outputs
- coded a callback method,  parameters being the inputs.  `return` is a **tuple** of all the outputs

#### full working example

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, dash_table
import dash_leaflet as dl
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

# set up some data that is missing from question
gdf = (
    gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
    .rename(columns={"iso_a3": "ANALYSISID"})
    .sample(30)
)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        c: gdf["ANALYSISID"] if c == "Analysis" else np.random.uniform(1, 30, len(gdf))
        for c in ["Analysis", "LGA", "SMA", "AVLU", "Address", "Locality", "AREA(HA)", "Sale Date"]  # fmt: skip
    }
)
dfb = df
df = df[["Analysis", "LGA", "SMA", "AVLU", "Address", "Locality", "AREA(HA)", "Sale Date"]]  # fmt: skip
gdf1 = gdf[["ANALYSISID", "geometry"]]
sales = gdf1.merge(dfb, left_on="ANALYSISID", right_on="Analysis")

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

# setup a layout missing from question, partial definition of callback
app.layout = html.Div(
    [html.Div(id=id) for id in ["my_output", "my_output1"]]
    + [dcc.Input(id=id, type="number") for id in ["factor2", "factor1"]]
    + [
        dcc.RadioItems(
            df["Analysis"].tolist(),
            df["Analysis"].tolist()[0],
            inline=True,
            id="radio_items",
        )
    ]
    + [dcc.Dropdown(["A", "B", "C"], "A", id=id) for id in ["SMA-dpdn", "LGA-dpdn"]]
    + [html.Div(id=id) for id in ["graph-container1", "graph-container", "map"]]
    + [
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id="table-container",
            columns=[
                {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.drop(columns=["Analysis"]).columns
            ],
        )
    ]
)

# many output and inputs so define them as iterators
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("graph-container1", "children"),
        Output("graph-container", "children"),
        Output("table-container", "data"),
        Output("my_output", "children"),
        Output("my_output1", "children"),
        Output("map", "children"),
    ],
    [
        Input("factor2", "value"),
        Input("factor1", "value"),
        Input("radio_items", "value"),
        Input("SMA-dpdn", "value"),
        Input("LGA-dpdn", "value"),
    ],
)
# call back that takes all parameters and returns all outputs
def big_cb(factor2, factor1, radio_items, sma_dpdn, lga_dpdn):
    # make graphs, table and map dependent on radio button selection
    df_ = df.loc[df["Analysis"].eq(radio_items)].drop(columns=["Analysis"])
    gdf_ = gdf1.loc[gdf1["ANALYSISID"].eq(radio_items)]
    return (
        dcc.Graph(figure=px.scatter(df_)),
        dcc.Graph(figure=px.bar(df_)),
        df_.to_dict("records"),
        factor2,
        radio_items,
        # dash-leaflet the question.  create using geojson from geopandas dataframe
        # centering is just for convenience
        dl.Map(
            [dl.TileLayer(), dl.GeoJSON(data=gdf_.__geo_interface__)],
            center=gdf_.unary_union.centroid.coords[0][::-1],
            style={"width": "1000px", "height": "500px"},
        ),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #     app.run_server(debug=True)
    app.run_server(mode="inline", debug=True, port=8051)
```